# How do I get the imaginary part (or real part) of an array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I have trouble with my N qubit wavefunction. I try to prepare a state `psi = a|0> + b*exp(2i\pi\theta)|1>`, and I wanted to check if the values for `b*exp(2i\pi\theta)` were well distributed.

Here is how I got my wavefunction :

```
N = 100
psi = np.full([100, 2], None)
for i in range(N) :
x = np.random.random()
y = y = np.exp(2j*np.pi*np.random.random())*np.sqrt(1-x**2)
psi[i] = [x,y]
```

I then used this line to get an array with only the y's and tried to plot them on the complex plane :

```
psi2 = psi[:,1]
plt.plot(psi2.real,psi2.imag)
```

I can't grasp why it doesn't plot the imaginary part and I just get :

[Result of psi2 in the complex plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg97t.png)

Comment: You should look at the [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html) module in python for complex Number

Comment: [this link](https://blog.furas.pl/python-complex-number-real-and-imaginary-part-gb.html) may help as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the output array `psi` "complex aware". An easy way is to fill it with complex values instead of `None` objects:

```
psi = np.full([100, 2], None)
print(psi.dtype)
# object  ... not good

psi = np.full([100, 2], 0j)
print(psi.dtype)
# complex128   ... numpy inferred the complex data type for psi
```

Now the `.real` and `.imag` attributes should work as expected.

```
plt.plot(psi2[:,1].real,psi2[:,1].imag, '.')
```

[image]